# Limiting the message size through Logback configuration

Tags: java, logback

I have java spring boot application and I am logging the log message and exception parameter combined like below using Logback.xml:

```
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <timestamp>
                    <fieldName>timestamp</fieldName>
                    <pattern>[UNIX_TIMESTAMP_AS_NUMBER]</pattern>
                </timestamp>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "application": "${APP_NAME}",
                        "message": "%.-4000msg%n%rEx{65}"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
```

Here I know how can I limit the msg size and exception size separately and that I have done above by limiting message size to 4000 characters and exception depth to 65.

But what I want is to specify a limit combined. E.g. combined message size and exception size should not exceed 6000 characters. How this can be achieved ?